# Trouble with a grid alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Seems like a simple thing at first, but becoming a bit more complex than I thought. I'm working on a simple portfolio site which I'm doing as one page with jquery to make it look like a full website. Currently my plan has been to have each piece of a content in its own div. I'll have the content, above, on either side and on the bottom. I specifically want to achieve this effect. How can I align these things so that there's a block of text to each of these directions, all aligned and in such a way that if there's window resizing the whole thing doesn't look broken?

Comment: Please post some code or an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to imagine what you are looking for. It would help if you post a sample code or a image of what you are looking for. But you could try style="float:left;width:100px" for the DIV tags. All div tags will appear stacked next to each other.

Also ensure you put these child DIV tags in a parent DIV tag with style="overflow:auto"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what do you mean, but i think you can look for a css floating grid system.

Here for a starting point: [CSS: Fun With Floating in the Grid](http://www.devlounge.net/code/css-fun-with-floating-in-the-grid)

Search for a grid system and look at the css definitions.